# Strange interaction between multi-page \tableofcontents and \pagenumbering{roman}

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

Take this document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{\LaTeX\ page numbering repro}
\author{Hendrik}

\begin{document}

%\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

%\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

It compiles correctly, such that

- title page and abstract are unnumbered,
- the first page of the ToC is page 1,
- the second page of the ToC is page 2,
- it continues with pages 3, 4, 5, ….

However, I would like everything before chapter 1 to use roman numbers, such that chapter 1 starts at page 1. To accomplish that, I added the `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` lines. If you uncomment them, the document still compiles, but there is a problem.

- Title page and abstract are still unnumbered. ✓
- First page of the ToC starts at i. ✓
- Second page of the ToC is now page 1. ❌ What? why??
- It continues with pages 2, 3, 4, …. ✓

I want the second page of the ToC to be numbered page ii instead. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `\pagenumbering{arabic}` when you were still on the page of the toc. The page break only happens when the chapter starts. So you either have to start the new page manually (e.g. `\clearpage`) or use it when the chapter has already started the new page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{\LaTeX\ page numbering repro}
\author{Hendrik}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents



\chapter{Chapter 1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\section{Section}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, that fixes the problem. Thanks a lot! Now I feel a bit stupid.

Comment: @Hendrikto You're welcome! (nice minimal working example in your question! I wish more users would post such questions!)